# Trig Identity Confusion

Tags: trigonometry

Solving a problem I came across $\cos^2(t) - \sin^2(t) + 1$. The back of the book has the next step answer as $\cos(2t) -1$. Using the double angle identity how is it possible to receive the $-1$?

Comment: It's just a typo.

Comment: The back of the book is wrong: $\color{blue}{\cos^2 t - \sin^2 t} + 1 = \color{blue}{\cos 2t} + 1$

Comment: Figured. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of minus it must be plus. 
the book is wrong and particularly good that you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The back of the book is wrong:

$$
\begin{align}
\color{green}{\cos^2(t) − \sin^2(t)} + 1
&\equiv\color{green}{\cos(t)\cdot\cos(t) − \sin(t)\cdot\sin(t)} + 1\\
&\equiv \color{green}{\cos(t+t)} + 1\\
&\equiv \color{green}{\cos(2t)} + 1
\end{align}
$$

Textbooks aren't perfect. There will always be little typos like this.